# Uncaught exception on malformed multipart error on prod env, not able to reproduce in local env

Tags: node.js, upload, postman, multer, multer-s3

I have been trying to reproduce this error using postman in the Nodejs server on my local but I am not able to do so.

QA was able to produce it once or twice by terminating the application while uploading the file which in turn threw the uncaught exception error on Kibana APM logs and crashed the server.

My aim is to crash the server on local once so that I can add exception handlers to avoid crashes on prod env.

I am using Multer with Multer S3

```
"multer": "^1.4.2",
"multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
```

here is my code

```
    uploadToS3: (fileFilter, limits, bcktName, awsS3Path) => { return multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: bcktName,
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, awsS3Path + Date.now().toString())
        }
      }),
    fileFilter:fileFilter,
    limits:{...limits}
    })
},
```

here is the complete error

```
Unexpected end of multipart data

         node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js in global.<anonymous> at line 62
          var self = this;
          self.emit('error', new Error('Unexpected end of multipart data'));
          if (self._part && !self._ignoreData) {
              var type = (self._isPreamble ? 'Preamble' : 'Part');
              internal/process/task_queues.js in processTicksAndRejections at line 75
```

controller code:

```
let upload = util.uploadToS3(fileFilter, limits, process.env.Bucket, path).single('file');
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log("inside upload");
        try {
            if (err instanceof multer.MulterError || (err && MULTER_ERROR_CODES[err.code || err.message])) {
                // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
                return res
                    .status(400)
                    .send(util.sendFormattedErrorResponse(MULTER_ERROR_CODES[err.code || err.message]));
            } else if (err) {
                // log error in kibana
                console.log(err);

                // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
                return res.status(500).send(util.sendFormattedErrorResponse(MULTER_ERROR_CODES['UNKNOWN']));
            }
        } catch (e) {
            // log error in kibana
            console.log(e);
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

PS: if you can also point me where to add the exception handlers it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback function to handle these errors,
Here is a reference link
https://github.com/expressjs/multer#error-handling

```
const multer = require('multer')
const upload = multer().single('avatar')

app.post('/profile', function (req, res) {
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      // A Multer error occurred when uploading.
    } else if (err) {
      // An unknown error occurred when uploading.
    }

    // Everything went fine.
  })
})
```

You can add a global error handler, Details about it is mentioned in this link
[Global Error Handler](https://blog.idrisolubisi.com/global-error-handling-in-node-js)

Comment: there is an error handler attached but still, it goes south.. don't know what is the reason.

Updating the post with the upload code.

Comment: @sidd Then you can try to add a global error handler on your express project. I hope that will catch the error

Comment: I've add a link to my answer, Please check

Comment: will add that no issues but how I can I be sure without reproducing the error that this method will work?, any ideas for reproducing the above error ?

Comment: I think you can deploy the build to any of your colleague's system, And use that as a production server, Or you can also use some free hosting server. I think that will be the only case to reproduce the error.